# Correct way to set up network with multiple routers/access points over fiber/ethernet

Tags: dhcp, lan, fiber, wan

### Heading

Below is a network map for a network.

[image: Network map]

Router `192.168.0.1` has DHCP enabled. Routers `0.2`, `0.3`, and `0.4` are connected via their LAN ports to router 0.1 by ethernet cable, and have DHCP disabled so that they act as access points. They each have separate SSIDs (the top line in the box for each, `Room 1`, `Room 2`, etc). Router `192.168.0.1` distributes IPs in the range `192.168.0.40-254`, as the printers/server have fixed IPs in the `.30`s.

Router `Nextbuildingover` (top right) is connected to `192.168.0.1` over fibre, through a set of media converters. On the `Nextbuildingover` router, the ethernet cable from the media converter goes into the WAN port. It has the IP `192.168.1.1`, and has DHCP enabled, in the range `192.168.1.100-254`

Is the fact the `Nextbuildingover` router is connected like this correct? Would it be better to connect it via a LAN port, give it the IP `192.168.0.5` and turn off DCHP work better, or does the fact it goes over fibre change things?

Aside from the `Nextbuildingover` router, are routers `0.2`, `0.3`, and `0.4` set up correctly? I have read conflicting advice, some saying they should have the same SSID, and others saying they need to be set up as bridges.

There are around 30 users across the access points. We frequently need to reset routers/access points to get things working again after the internet connection drops and laptops report 'No internet connection'. I don't know if it is caused by an incorrect setup, or cheap hardware. All hardware is TP Link, of various models.

Comment: What type of routers are these? For example, you have the same network on two different router interfaces on the `192.168.0.2` router, but routers route between networks, not from a network back to the same network. The router will have no way to determine which interface to send the traffic destined for that network.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You can ask about those for a business network on [sf].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the fact the Nextbuildingover router is connected like this correct?

Yes, it is correct.

> Would it be better to connect it via a LAN port, give it the IP 192.168.0.5 and turn off DCHP work better

Sure, you can make it as a single subnet instead of two as long as you are ok with the number of users/broadcasts in it and have no security requirements.

It will not work better per se, but it might be easier for your users to share resources over a single network.

> does the fact it goes over fibre change things?

Not much, unless it has some speed limitations.

> Aside from the Nextbuildingover router, are routers 0.2, 0.3, and 0.4 set up correctly?

Looks ok to me. You did not mention it, you must use different channels on the adjacent access points.

You might also consider to connect meeting room and office switches directly.

> I have read conflicting advice, some saying they should have the same SSID, and others saying they need to be set up as bridges.

Same SSID helps mobile users to move between the access points. If your users are static - it does not matter.

> We frequently need to reset routers/access points to get things working again after the internet connection drops.

It is hard to guess, you have to track down the issue to its source. Probably you have just one faulty router and you do not have to reset all of them...